# Проблема с наложением одного блока на другой

Tags: javascript, html, css

Здравствуйте есть слайд шоу с автопрокруткой картинок, и есть отдельный блок в котором расположены круги которые показывают какая картинка сейчас на экране. Но проблема в том что я не могу разместить эти круги прямо на картинках, размещал их в разных местах, на скриншоте показан самый лучший вариант которого я добился. Проблема в том что не происходит наложение, картинка сужается в высоте, и хотел бы что бы круги были внизу а не сверху как у меня. И ещё одна проблема, когда заменяю чёрный цвет в rds на картинку картинка не отображается фон пропадает и остаются только круги.

код html:

```
<?php Header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index-css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container/swap.css">
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      gallery.init(5);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="rds" onclick="gallery.slide(event)">
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn1"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn2"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn3"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn4"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn5"></span>
    </div>
         <div class="photo">
             <div class="container-photo" id="container_image">
                 <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/1.png" /></span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/2.png" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/3.png" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/4.png" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/5.png" /></span>
                </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="container/swap.js"></script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

код css:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

.photo {
  float: left;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-photo {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
}
.image-block {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.rds {
  display: block;
  line-height: 150%;
  width: 780px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 3;
}
.rds-bl {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-image: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  z-index: 4;
}
```

код js:

```
var gallery = {
  cnt: 0,
  container: document.getElementById("container_image"),
  timer: null,
  rds: "btn1",
  pos: 0,
  top: 1,
  init: function(i) {
    this.cnt = i;
    this.container.style.width = i * 780 + "px";
    this.timer = setInterval(function() {
      gallery.start();
    }, 4000);
  },
  start: function() {
    if (this.top == 1) {
      this.pos = 0;
      this.top += 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn4").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn5").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    } else if (this.top == 2) {
      this.pos -= 390 * 2;
      this.top += 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn4").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn5").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    } else if (this.top == 3) {
      this.pos -= 390* 2;
      this.top += 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.getElementById("btn4").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn5").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    } else if (this.top == 4) {
      this.pos -= 390 * 2;
      this.top += 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn4").style.backgroundColor = "white";
      document.getElementById("btn5").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
    } else if (this.top == 5) {
      this.pos -= 390 * 2;
      this.top = 1;
      document.getElementById("btn1").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn2").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn3").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn4").style.backgroundColor = "gray";
      document.getElementById("btn5").style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
    this.container.style.left = this.pos + "px";
  },
  slide: function(event) {
    var e = event || window.event;
    var target = e.target;

    if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "span") return;

    var id_click = target.id;
    var pos = document.getElementById(id_click).offsetLeft;
    if (id_click == "btn1") pos = 0;
    else if (id_click == "btn2") pos -= 571.5 * 2;
    else if (id_click == "btn3") pos -= 648.5 * 3;
    else if (id_click == "btn4") pos -= 730 * 4;
    else if (id_click == "btn5") pos -= 745 * 5;
    else pos = 247;
    this.container.style.left = pos + "px";
  }
}
```

скриншот:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После долгих обсуждений и вывода рабочего примера на jsfiddle удалось облагородить код и привести его к такому виду:

Рабочий пример на jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ipshenicyn/crvjbgaL/1/

**HTML**

```
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
      <div class="clear"></div>
      <div class="rds">
        <span class="rds-bl active" id="btn0" data-index=0></span>
        <span class="rds-bl" id="btn1" data-index=1></span>
        <span class="rds-bl" id="btn2" data-index=2></span>
        <span class="rds-bl" id="btn3" data-index=3></span>
        <span class="rds-bl" id="btn4" data-index=4></span>
      </div>
      <div class="photo">
        <div class="container-photo" id="container_image">
          <div class="image-block">
            <span>1</span>
          </div>
          <div class="image-block">
            <span>2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="image-block">
            <span>3</span>
          </div>
          <div class="image-block">
            <span>4</span>
          </div>
          <div class="image-block">
            <span>5</span>
          </div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**JS**

```
window.gallery = {
  container: document.getElementById("container_image"),
  timer: null,
  currentSlide: 0, //номер текущего слайда
  slidesCount: null, //сколько всего слайдов
  oneSlideWidth: null, //ширина одного слайда
  init: function(i) {
    //внутри нашего контейнера со слайдами находим все слайды (блоки с классом image-block)
    var slides = this.container.getElementsByClassName('image-block');    
    //узнаем и сохраняем количество слайдов
    this.slidesCount = slideCount = slides.length;
    //узнаем и сохраняем ширину первого из слайдов
    this.oneSlideWidth = oneSlideWidth = slides[0].offsetWidth;
    this.container.style.width = slideCount * this.oneSlideWidth + "px";

    this.timer = setInterval(function() {
      gallery.start();
    }, 3000);
  },
  start: function() {
    //считаем, какой "следующий номер слайда". если сейчас пятый - следующий первый. 
    var nextSlide = this.currentSlide == (this.slidesCount - 1) ? 0 : this.currentSlide + 1;    
    //находим нужную кнопку (следующего слайда) и вызываем на ней клик
    document.getElementById("btn" + nextSlide).click();
  },
  slide: function(event) {

    //в this у нас ссылка на текущую кнопку, по которой произошел клик
    var button = this;

    //в currentSlide сохраняем номер текущего слайда
    gallery.currentSlide = parseInt(button.getAttribute('data-index'));

    //смещение слайда равно "- [номер слайда] * [ширина одного слайда]"
    gallery.container.style.left = -(gallery.currentSlide * gallery.oneSlideWidth) + "px";

    //находим все кнопки и убираем у них класс active
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("rds-bl");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
      btns[i].className = "rds-bl";
    }
    //добавляем класс active нужной кнопке
    button.className = 'rds-bl active';
  }
};

//находим все кнопки переключения слайдов по их классу rds-bl
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("rds-bl");
for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    //вешаем слушатель события click: при срабатывании клика на кнопке будет вызван gallery.slide
    btns[i].addEventListener('click', gallery.slide);
}

//этот кусок нужно расположите в window.onload, как и было.
gallery.init();
```

**CSS**

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 940px;
  padding-top: 42px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

.photo {
  float: left;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.container-photo {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.image-block {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

.rds {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 256px;
  line-height: 150%;
  width: 780px;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.rds-bl {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 4;
}

.rds-bl.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за корректировки, если вас не затруднит можно вас пожалуйста попросить подробней описать код js не совсем разобрался как поменять и как подправить код html что бы активную при клике показывал

Comment: @Sambl дополнил ответ. Если остались вопросы - уточните, с чем конкретно сложности.

Comment: Я заранее прошу прощение, я слаб в javascript ниже добавил ответ, с подробными кодами, но скорее всего сделал что то не то, потому что не работает. Слайды меняются а кнопок нет, пожалуйста если не трудно, исправьте мой код как правильно.

Comment: @Sambl ну вот( правил, а вы удалили( разобрались?

Comment: Скопировал код, но всё равно кнопки не отобразились, картинки меняются, но кнопок нет

Comment: @Sambl может быть я вас не понимаю... что значит "кнопок нет"? их нет на странице? или вы второй раз опечатались и имели ввиду "кнопки не меняются"? а класс добавляется им при клике, проверьте?

Comment: как можете посмотреть на скриншоте сверху, там на картинке вверху есть 5 серых кнопок. После того как вставил ваш код все эти круги пропали

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43637/discussion-between-sambl-and--).

Answer (score 0):

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="icon" href="images/icon.png" type="image/x-icon">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index-css.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="container/swap.css">
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
      gallery.init(5);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="rds" onclick="gallery.slide(event)">
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn1"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn2"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn3"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn4"></span>
      <span class="rds-bl" id="btn5"></span>
    </div>
         <div class="photo">
             <div class="container-photo" id="container_image">
                 <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/1.png" /></span>
                 </div>
                 <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/2.png" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/3.png" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/4.png" /></span>
                </div>
                <div class="image-block">
                     <span><img src="container/images/5.png" /></span>
                </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="non-game">
     <div id="timer">
     </div>
     <div id="non-game-image">
     <img src="images/non-game/1.png" />
     </div>
  </div>  
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="container/swap.js"></script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

css:

```
#container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.photo {
  float: left;
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.container-photo {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s;
  transition: all 1s;
  position: relative;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.image-block {
  width: 780px;
  height: 280px;
  float: left;
  background: pink;
  border-top-left-radius: 5px;
  border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}
.clear {
  clear: both;
}
.rds {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 256px;
    line-height: 150%;
    width: 780px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 3;
}
.rds-bl {
  width: 13px;
  height: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  background-image: gray;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;  
  z-index: 4;
}
.rds.active {
    background-color: white;
}
```

js:

```
var gallery = {
    cnt: 0,
    container: document.getElementById("container_image"),
    timer: null,
    rds: "btn1",
    pos: 0,
    top: 1,
    init: function(i) {
        this.cnt = i;
        this.container.style.width = i * 780 + "px";
        this.timer = setInterval(function() {
            gallery.start();
        }, 4000);
    },
    start: function() {
        //находим все кнопки и убираем у них класс active 
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("rds-bl");
        for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
            btns[i].className = "rds-bl";
        }
        //добавляем класс active нужной кнопке 
        document.getElementById("btn" + this.top).className = 'rds-bl active';

        this.pos = this.top == 1 ? 0 : (this.pos - 390 * 2);
        this.top = this.top == 5 ? 1 : (this.top + 1);

        this.container.style.left = this.pos + "px";
    },
    slide: function(event) {
        var e = event || window.event;
        var target = e.target;

        if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() != "span") return;

        var id_click = target.id;
        var button = document.getElementById(id_click);
        var pos = button.offsetLeft;

        if (id_click == "btn1") {
            pos = 0;
            gallery.top = 1;
        } else if (id_click == "btn2") {
            pos -= 571.5 * 2;
            gallery.top = 2;
        } else if (id_click == "btn3") {
            pos -= 648.5 * 3;
            gallery.top = 3;
        } else if (id_click == "btn4") {
            pos -= 730 * 4;
            gallery.top = 4;
        } else if (id_click == "btn5") {
            pos -= 745 * 5;
            gallery.top = 5;
        } else {
            pos = 247;
        }

        //находим все кнопки и убираем у них класс active
        var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("rds-bl");
        for(var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++){
            btns[i].className = "rds-bl";
        }
        //добавляем класс active нужной кнопке
        button.className = 'rds-bl active';

        gallery.pos = pos;
        this.container.style.left = pos + "px";
    }
}
```